# iOS - Constraints in TableView

Tags: ios, constraints, tableview

[image]

[image]

Sorry for redness, but I have to hide the information.
After zeros I have word, but when the word is short the zeros moves.
lines 1,2,3,4 word letters 5
line 5 word letters 2
line 6 word letters 4
How to stop the zeros from moving ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html

Under: Creating Equal Spacing Between Views

Comment: I have only 1 view... tableview with labels inside and why thats happend when they have equal widths ?

Comment: The labels would be the multiple views

Comment: I still can't arrange the labels... They moving every time when the values are different